# Call a method pass from parent component to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent stateful react component that has a function that will change when an html span is clicked within the child component. I want to pass that method to the child component and call it when the snap is clicked I then want to pass it back up to the parent component and updated the state based on what is passed back up. I am having trouble passing down the method and calling it within the child component...

parent component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            dates: [],
            workouts: [],
            selectedDate: '',
            selectedWorkouts: []
        }

        this.updateDateAndWorkouts = this.updateDateAndWorkouts.bind(this)
        axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3001"
    }

    updateDateAndWorkouts = () => {
        console.log('clicked')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DateBar data={this.state.dates}/>
                <ClassList workouts={this.state.selectedWorkouts} updateDate={this.updateDateAndWorkouts}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

This is the child component:

```
export default function Datebar(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.data.map((day, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <span onClick={props.updateDate}>
                            {day}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I want to happen is when the method is called in thechild component, it calls the method that was passed and pass the text within the span div...

Comment: You're not passing any function here: `<DateBar data={this.state.dates}/>`

Comment: What specifically isn't working? You don't pass a function to `Datebar`, you do pass one to `ClassList`. Also, you don't need to `bind` arrow functions manually--that's one of the points of arrow functions.

Comment: `<DateBar data={this.state.dates} updateDate={this.updateDateAndWorkouts}/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually pass function to child component

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            dates: [],
            workouts: [],
            selectedDate: '',
            selectedWorkouts: []
        }

        this.updateDateAndWorkouts = this.updateDateAndWorkouts.bind(this)
        axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3001"
    }

    updateDateAndWorkouts = () => {
        console.log('clicked')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DateBar data={this.state.dates} updateDate={this.updateDateAndWorkouts} />
                <ClassList workouts={this.state.selectedWorkouts} updateDate={this.updateDateAndWorkouts}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: that is working now. i feel stupid. I have a question. when I run it and `consoe.log(e.target)` I get `<span value="2019-08-10">2019-08-10</span>`. I want to grab just the `2019-08-10`. when i do `console.log(e.target.value)` it throws an undefined. do you know what i should do for that.

Comment: @OmarJandali ... Spans don't have values, they have content.

Comment: so would it better to switch the selector or the call to e.target.content @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

You have to call that method in child component

```
props.updateDate()

export default function Datebar(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.data.map((day, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <span onClick={props.updateDate()}>
                            {day}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's wrong. You'll end up passing the return value of updateDateAndWorkouts (which is undefined) to the onClick handler instead of the function callback itself